# Replicate GLKView in another view?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Both Google Maps and Map Box draw their maps in a `GLKView`:

[image: View hierarchy for Map Box iOS SDK]

[image: View hierarchy description]

I need to replicate the area the user is touching into a magnifying glass similar to the copy paste bubble that is generic to the iOS Operating system.

After following a few tutorials and looking at [YPMagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/GJNilsen/YPMagnifyingGlass) and [iOS-MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass) written in Objective - C I can get it to replicate any `UIView`. Note the replicated view is offset ~100 PX from the touch point.

[image]

However this technique fails to replicate the `GLKView` that the map is drawn on:

[image]

Anyone who knows more about Open GL than me know how to do this? Any other suggestions on how to make a Magnifying glass are welcome also.

Comment: `GLKView` images are `CIImages`. If you simply took the  CIImage and passed it to another GLKView, what do you get? (I do this alot, but with normal images - Google maps may have overlays on them. I also have a GLKView with `UIView` subviews in it. I then create a `CIImage` of it.)